# Getting error in selenium test cases

Tags: selenium

I'm running somebody written selenium test cases in my system.It showing the few errors like

```
> [error] Actual value 'null' did not match '[object Object]' 
> [error] Threw an exception: this.browserbot.getUserWindow().map is undefined 
> [error] Threw an exception: this.browserbot.getUserWindow().map is undefined
```

Is it the problem with selenium ide version which I'm using or other? I'm using Selenium 1.6.0

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your script.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/projectName</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertEval</td>
 <td>this.browserbot.getUserWindow().map</td>
 <td>[object Object]</td>
</tr>

Comment: above script is for first error

Comment: this is problem because actual value is not matching with expected value..this problem is not because of selenium version

Comment: this.browserbot.getUserWindow().map  returns null for your case. It should return [object Object] to run script successfully..if possible share project name..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8583/discussion-between-mahesh-d-and-rohit-ware)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is coming because you are trying to get hold of a window , which is not matching to the value you are passing.
So for this you need to investigate more on your locators. Also you can start using a new tool which can find automatically the locators for you , which is Selenium Builder. Hope following links will help you.

http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/selenium-builder-exporting-and-execution/

http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/selenium-builder/

Answer (score 0):

Those errors you're getting are not because of Selenium version, but because the logic of your application changed and the tests expect different results from various actions.

The only thing you can do is to go through your tests, discover what were they trying to assert / achieve / test (you do have your testcases documented, right?) and if their current behaviour is wrong, fix them.

The other possibility is that your tests are ok, just the application began to behave differently (against the spec) and needs to be fixed. But from the context, I'd say that your unmaintained tests broke.